# What is the exact meaning of "for its own uses"?

Tags: grammatical-number

This phrase seems grammatically speaking incorrect.

> The Mosaic symbolism is very significant, because from it Freemasonry has derived and transmitted **for its own uses** many of the most precious treassures.

I think in any case it should be "for their own uses", it seems there is no number agreement and it should be such thing.

Comment: Why do you think it should be "their"? Where's the plural noun?

Comment: I think the author could've said "for its own use" I am a native Spanish speaker and in my language it sounds really weird, now I can understand why in English it is correct.

Comment: But in the question you said it should be "*for **their** own **uses***". Which is it?

Comment: I suggested that phrase as the author is saying "uses" a plural noun. So for the agreement I suggested their which is wrong. I think he doesn't need to use the plural as he could've used the singular conveying almost the same meaning.

Comment: There are many uses though, not just one

Answer (score 3):

"Freemasonry" is singular, and "it" refers to this singular noun.

"For" is a preposition, and here it indicates a purpose. The purpose given is freemasonry's own uses.  That is, the purpose of the Mosaic symbolism is for freemasonry's use, and not to benefit some other organisation.

Answer (score 2):

No, the subject is “Freemasonry,” a singular noun, with a singular verb, “has,” and so “its” is grammatically consistent. In fact, there is no plural noun preceding “its.”